# How can I make Selenium click 'Open' on a PDF download page using C# and handle the iframe selection?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, chrome-web-driver

Unable to click open in pdf download page using C# selenium. how to make the driver understand the iframe and make the selection?

PDF download page

[image]

Selenium code I tried:

```
   driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
   driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
   driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Open")).Click();
```

Facing this issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a child frame in your case asking for a password but you are active in a parent frame you will not see changes nor be able to access the PDF viewers contents you can only change your own surroundings

[image]

What is odd about your image is there should be a modal Password request to open a secured PDF.

[image]